# Making Microsoft SQL server being installed on app installation

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, installation, desktop

So I'm ending my application and I would like to make that Microsoft SQL Server installs before my app installation, so basically :

1. Microsoft SQL Server starts to install -> if it's already installed then a new instance of database is going to be made at that moment or if user selects proper option then this point won't be evaluated at all
2. Then the app installation starts.
3. Then there is a choice between automatic and manual connection to database. Automatic -> it takes connection data from previously made instance.
   Manual -> user provides connection data.
4. After the installation the connection data to database must be provided to app configuration file somehow.

Do you guys have any idea how to made that complicated installer and what tool should I use to make it quick and good ?

Answer (score 1):

You can silently install a specific instance of SQL server (before you install your app) with known connection details that only your app uses.

Or your app can request connection details from the user after installation on [initial] start up if it cannot find SQL Server instance that it needs.

In both cases you would need to run sql scripts to create your DB and User logon for SQL Server...

here is a list of free and not free installation software...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Could you recommend me which one of these installers would be suitable ?

Comment: They will all do pretty much the same job, some futures might be disabled with the free versions tho... You could actually write your own C#/VB project to install SQL Server and copy your application files to the target machine....